# Read csv data, then append text file with values at specific places

Tags: python, csv, text, append

I just started with Python and do not have a good hold of all the functions and methods used in Python.  Hope someone can give me pointers in this regard.
Q: I am trying to read a CSV file containing x, y, and z data in multiple rows. I then need to take those read values and replace them in a text file at specific places.
I am able to use csv.reader for reading the file but I'm having tough time in locating the right function to search and append data in my text file.

The CSV file contains;

> ```
> X  Y  Z
> ```
>
> 1 x1 y1 z1
>
> 2 x2 y2 z2
>
> 3 x3 y3 z3

The text file contains:

```
This is first text line.
The data goes here x1 with y1 and z1
also goes here x2 wtih y2 and z2.
```

I was able to make some progress with writing the data in a new text file as a first step:

```
import csv
testfile = open('Data.csv', "rb")
reader =  csv.reader(testfile)
rownum = 0
file=open("detdata.txt", "w")
for row in reader:
    # Save header row.
    if rownum == 0:
    *
    *
```

Comment: what is the main question in here? please complete my assignment?

Comment: Are the text's lines number supposed to match the CSV row numbers, ie first line of text will only get variables from the first row, second line of text from the second row etc, or are they all mixed all over the text ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: Thanks for your prompt response. Yes, the numbers in csv file row 2 (x1, y1,..) need to go to their specific location in line 2 in the text file. Each variable (a value) in csv file need to go to a pre-assigned location in text file wihich has some default values already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Braindead, brittle, inefficient and untested solution:

```
source = open("/path/to/textfile.txt").read()
keys = ("x", "y", "z")
reader.next() # discard the headers row
for num, row in enumerate(reader, 1):
    for key, val in zip(keys, row):
        varname = "{0}{1}".format(key, num)
        source = source.replace(varname, val)
```

A better solution would be to use a template string in the text file with Python's string formatting markers, ie:

```
This is first text line.
The data goes here {x1} with {y1} and {z1}
also goes here {x2} wtih {y2} and {z2}.
```

then collect the `varname`:`values` pairs in a `dict` and use `str.format()`:

```
data = dict()
keys = ("x", "y", "z")
reader.next() # discard the headers row
for num, row in enumerate(reader, 1):
    for key, val in zip(keys, row):
        varname = "{0}{1}".format(key, num)
        data[varname] = val

source = open("/path/to/textfile.txt").read()
result = source.format(**data)
```

but note that if you have placeholders in the text with no matching key in the `dict` you'll get an error.

Comment: Hi Bruno, thanks for your suggestions on this. The reader.next() function does not work for me for some reason ;(